# Oracle sql query to get the list of customers who purchased more than one item

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

```
Customers (customer_id,customer_name)
Orders (order_id, order_date, customer_id)
Order_details (order_id, item_id)
Items (item_id)
```

I need an oracle sql query to get the list of customers who purchased more than one item..Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sure.let me add what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see if this works :

```
select c.* from customers c, orders o, order_details od 
where c.customer_id = o.customer_id 
    and o.order_id = od.order_id 
    group by od.order_id having count(od.item_id) > 1;
```

Comment: I would never encourage the use of this deprecated join syntax.

Comment: @GoatCO can you please elaborate..its been long since I wrote SQL Query,so if you can provide more insight into the correct way to write Join query it would be helpful for me as well as others.

Comment: This helped me .I thought we could join all the four tables .But since item_id is also present in the order_details table .This query worked out for me .Thank you!

Comment: @user3338753 You are welcome. Though this might not be the most efficient way to write a query. You should try some other optimizations too.

Comment: But could you also help me out with join condition using three tables

Comment: Yea .I am trying out with the join condition .It could be more effective way I guess.

Comment: @SushilDhaundiyal Sure thing, implicit joins have been removed from the SQL standard for ~20 years.  The standard now calls for explicit joins, as seen in Will P's answer.  Performance-wise there is no difference.

Comment: @GoatCO Thanks a lot for the reply. I had a question though from the perspective of Database Optimization engine..it will eventually convert all Implict joins to the appropriate Inner Joins to optimize the DB Query, thats the reason why I always take the liberty of not mentioning the Join syntax. But you are right specifying the Join syntax makes it more clearer for the person reading the code.

Comment: @SushilDhaundiyal It's true they are equivalent in the eyes of the optimizer.  Some databases do not allow outer joins using this old syntax.  It's not fully deprecated, just not standard anymore.

Comment: I have tried it in this way .  select customer_first_name ,number_of_items from (select cus.customer_first_name ,count(od.item_id) as number_of_items
from customers cus,order_details od,orders o
where o.customer_id=cus.customer_id
and od.order_id=o.order_id
group by cus.customer_first_name having count(od.item_id)>1)
order by number_of_items desc;

Answer (score 1):

This should do, it will also include a column showing the number of orders:

```
SELECT Count(item_id) order_count, customer_id, customer_name
FROM Customers
   INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
   INNER JOIN Order_details ON Orders.order_id = Order_details.order_id
GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name
HAVING Count(item_id) > 1
```